# i have to write a MySql query to find out names of users who have organised events sorted in order

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables **user** and **events.**
the query to be written is to find the names of users who have organized events

**query 1**:

```
select user.name
from user, events
where user.id = events.organiser_id
order by user.name;
```

**query 2**:

```
select name 
from user 
where id in(select organiser_id from events) 
order by name;
```

why is it that "**query 2**" works fine but "**query 1**" doesn't? How to decide on when to use a subquery or a join?

Comment: The only difference I see between the two queries is that the first one will contain duplicates if a user is signed up for more than one event.  Also, you should stop using the implicit `join` syntax (`,` in the `from` clause).  This was deprecated with the `ANSI-92` standard (from 1992... over 25 years ago...), and this type of join is not fully supported.

Comment: `JOIN` is equivalent to a ***correlated*** sub-query. Yours is **not**.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "works fine but query 1 doesn't".  What do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: @gview i was solving a sql module where query2 got accepted but query 1 did not provide the correct output. so, i am confused why it's happening.

Comment: It's probably because you were missing DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

A typical join syntax for mysql would be:

```
select distinct user.name 
from user 
join events ON events.organiser_id = user.id 
order by user.name;
```

Comment: Sure, if that is desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    U.Name
    FROM USER U
    LEFT JOIN
    EVENTS E
    ON U.id = E.organiser_id
    WHERE E.organiser_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY U.Name
```

use JOIN to select all users and related events then filter with WHERE to exclude those users who do not have a link (an id in the event table); if there are more events for each user in the event table, then DISTINCT must be used (this in T-SQL)

Comment: question is tagged with mysql

Answer (score -3):

The second query doesn't work because the column name doesn't match. You have one that says, "id in (select organiser_id". If you did this, it would work, "id in (select organiser_id as id"